# Problem generating pdf on AWS using wkhtmltox-0.12.6-4.amazonlinux2_lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, wkhtmltopdf

I am generating a pdf in aws from an html string using wkhtmltox-0.12.6-4.amazonlinux2_lambda.zip and the wkhtmltopdf installer. I have configured in serverless the layers and the function. The html code has integrated CSS styles in the tags. Currently the pdf is saved in S3 but does not apply the defined css styles.

I tried to generate a pdf from an html code and expected to get the document with the proposed layout